# How to specify a default Sort with Hotchocolate and EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core, hotchocolate

Is there a way to add a Default Sort field, so that I can `UsePaging` and `UserSorting`, but if no order is specified I add a field, such as Id. But if the user does specify an order, then don't add the default.

For example, I can add the default sort to the query method, but then no other sorting works

```
[UseContext]
[UsePaging]
[UseProjection]
[UseFiltering]
[UseSorting]
public IQueryable<Property> GetProperties([ScopedService] PropContext dbContext)
{
    return dbContext.Properties
                    .OrderBy(p => p.Id); // Default sort by Prop Id
}
```

If don't have a sort, then Entity Framework shows a warning:

> The query uses a row limiting operator ('Skip'/'Take') without an 'OrderBy' operator.
> This may lead to unpredictable results

And I've seen some unexpected results

Answer (score 5):

Credit to S Blomstrand

Using these extension methods

```
public static bool HasOrderByArgument(this IResolverContext context,
                                       string argumentName = "order")
{
    try
    {
        var orderByArgument = context.ArgumentLiteral<IValueNode>(argumentName);
        if (orderByArgument != NullValueNode.Default && orderByArgument != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}

public static IQueryable<T> OrderByArgumentOrDefault<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, IResolverContext context, 
                                                        Func<IQueryable<T>> func, string argumentName = "order")
{
    if (context.HasOrderByArgument(argumentName))
    {
        return query;
    }

    return func.Invoke();
}
```

It can then be call as follows:

```
[UseContext]
[UsePaging]
[UseProjection]
[UseFiltering]
[UseSorting]
public IQueryable<Property> GetProperties([ScopedService] PropContext dbContext)
{
    return dbContext.Properties
                    .OrderByArgumentOrDefault(context, () => properties.OrderBy(p => p.Id));
}
```

Comment: Hey this worked for me, but it did take me a few extra minutes to figure out what files the extension methods needed to go in.  Is there any chance you could provide some more context around this to help folks out in the future?

Comment: The extension methods can go in any static class that you then import the namespace with using <namespace> into your query class. Its basic extension method usage, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: This approach will avoid the Entity Framework warning being emitted, but still won't guarantee predictable results if: (1) the order *is* specified in the GraphQL query, and (2) the fields used for order do not produce a strict unique ordering of all records.

I'm not sure how it might be achieved, but if it was somehow possible to arrange for `properties.OrderBy(p => p.Id)` to be called after any ordering has been applied based on the GraphQL query then that would avoid the problems (assuming p.Id is a unique identifier for Property records).

Answer (score 1):

the Kerr/Blomstrand answer to this question didn't quite work for me as written

The following changes did work:

- you need an `IResolverContext` argument in the query method (the runtime will fill it, no attribute needed)
- change the `Func` to an `Expression`

```cs
   public static IQueryable<T> OrderByArgumentOrDefault<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> query,
        IResolverContext context,
        Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>>> expression,
        string argumentName = "order")
    {
        return context.HasOrderByArgument(argumentName) ? query : expression.Compile().Invoke();
    }
```

```cs
public IQueryable<Property> GetProperties(
  [ScopedService] PropContext dbContext,
  IResolverContext context)
{
    return dbContext.Properties
                    .OrderByArgumentOrDefault(context, () => dbContext.Properties.OrderBy(p => p.Id));
}
```